# Python sort unique list of lists' items

Tags: python, list, sorting, unique

I can't seem to find a question on SO about my particular problem, so forgive me if this has been asked before!

Anyway, I'm writing a script to loop through a set of URL's and give me a list of unique urls with unique parameters.

The trouble I'm having is actually comparing the parameters to eliminate multiple duplicates. It's a bit hard to explain, so some examples are probably in order:

Say I have a list of URL's like this

- hxxp://www.somesite.com/page.php?id=3&title=derp
- hxxp://www.somesite.com/page.php?id=4&title=blah
- hxxp://www.somesite.com/page.php?id=3&c=32&title=thing
- hxxp://www.somesite.com/page.php?b=33&id=3

I have it parsing each URL into a list of lists, so eventually I have a list like this:

```
sort = [['id', 'title'], ['id', 'c', 'title'], ['b', 'id']]
```

I nee to figure out a way to give me just 2 lists in my list at that point:

```
new = [['id', 'c', 'title'], ['b', 'id']]
```

As of right now I've got a bit to sort it out a little, I know I'm close and I've been slamming my head against this for a couple days now :(. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: Sorry for not being clear! This script is aimed at finding unique entry points for web applications post-spidering. Basically if a URL has 3 unique entry points

```
['id', 'c', 'title']
```

I'd prefer that to the same link with 2 unique entry points, such as:

```
['id', 'title']
```

So I need my new list of lists to eliminate the one with 2 and prefer the one with 3 ONLY if the smaller variables are in the larger set. If it's still unclear let me know, and thank you for the quick responses! :)

Comment: what's the rule? what if there is a `['c', 'b']` or `['b', 'id', 'c']` and `['b', 'id', 'd']`?

Comment: I don't understand. What is `['id', 'title']` a duplicate of? Is it because it's a subset of `['id', 'c', 'title']`?

Comment: Both yi and Marcelo are right, your criteria aren't well defined.

Comment: I apologize  for not being clear. Basically I'm a web application tester, and after crawling a site, I'm looking for unique entry points. So having a list of URL's with the same entry points is no use to me. If id, and title are on the same page as id, title, and c, then the url with 3 variable entry points would be the useful link to have then the same one with 2. I'll re-edit my question though and try to clarify! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume that subsets are considered "duplicates" (non-commutatively, of course)...

Start by converting each query into a set and ordering them all from largest to smallest. Then add each query to a new list if it isn't a subset of an already-added query. Since any set is a subset of itself, this logic covers exact duplicates:

```
a = []
for q in sorted((set(q) for q in sort), key=len, reverse=True):
    if not any(q.issubset(Q) for Q in a):
        a.append(q)
a = [list(q) for q in a] # Back to lists, if you want
```

Comment: I do believe we have a winner! Amazing - Thank you very much. I'll be testing with a larger subset, but this seems to work amazingly! :) :)